# Kendo Ui and React js

Tags: reactjs, kendo-grid

Kendo Ui and React js
How can I use the Kendo UI MultiSelect as a column editor in a Kendo UI Grid Using React Js?

I have try to put multiselect inside kendo ui gride column but not working.

```
<Column >
  <Multiselect
        data={sports}
 onChange={handleChange}
        value={value}
        textField="text"
        dataItemKey="id"
        style={{
          width: "300px",
        }}
        placeholder="Please select ..."
       ></Colum>a
```

I am new in react and kendo UI can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

The KendoReact MultiSelect is a form component that displays a list of options and allows for multiple selections from this list and supports custom rendering of popup items and tags, header and footer elements,

[useful][1]
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dropdowns/multiselect/

```
 <MultiSelect
              label="User "
              data={role}
              value={value}
              onChange={handleChange}
              style={{
                width: "300px",
              }}
              placeholder="Please select ..."
            />
```